# Retrieving last n values from treemap

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap

I merely want to retrieve the last n values from a tree map without considering any keys or values from the map. But i really don't have any clue on how to do this. Below is a sample piece of code which can pull out first 5 records from the map. How can i modify it to retrieve last n records from the map?

```
Map startValues = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(5);
iterator = sortedMap.entrySet().iterator();
for (int i1 = 0; iterator.hasNext() && i1 < 5; i1++) {
    startValues.add(iterator.next());
}
```

Comment: A tree map is often sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, so you wont necessarily get the last 5 entries that were added.

Comment: last n values?? have you gone through this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Answer (score 4):

If `sortedMap` variable contains an instance of a `TreeMap` then use [`descendingKeySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#descendingKeySet%28%29). It returns a reverse order of the keys contained in there.

```
Map startValues = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(5);
iterator = sortedMap.descendingKeySet().iterator();
for (int i1 = 0; iterator.hasNext() && i1 < 5; i1++) {
   startValues.add(sortedMap.get(iterator.next()));
}
```

Note that in contrast to original code this iterates over **keys**, not entries. I have not test-compiled it so there might be minor issues with generics and type casting but hopefully the main idea is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Ordering in `TreeMap` maintained by `Comparator` object at the creation time. If `Comparator` not provided - it is *natural ordering*.

The most straightforward solution to create `Comparator` that implements *reverse sorting*, pass this comparator to new `TreeMap`, and add all elements from old treemap to new one. That way you can reuse you code sample for retrieving last 5 records.

Answer (score 0):

Get map.keySet() and convert it into ArrayList, then you can get last n values using loop as in example below:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put(1, "Praveen");
map.put(2, "shristi");
map.put(3, "tarang");
Set<Integer> keys = map.keySet();
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(keys);
for(int i=1;i<list.size();i++) {
  System.out.println(map.get(list.get(i)));
}
```